# database from multiple text files in python

Tags: python, database

I am trying to improve a python code I recently wrote that opens a text file containing a list of energies, like this:

```
6.36271
5.37679
165.742
6.53952
...
```

and for each entry it searches if the energy is present in any of the files contained in a dedicated folder (that have the same format). If the energy is found it returns the name of the file where it has been found and the energy itself.

The problem is that the number of files is very large (>1000), and each one has a lot of energies to look into.

The software works, but it is very slow because it has to open every file every time it searches for an entry, and I understood that it would work a lot faster if I could load all the files into a database and then query it.

The problem is that I never worked with databases and I have literally no idea of how to create such database from all the thousand of files (keeping track of the file name), and how to search into that once it has been created

If someone could give me a hand I would be very grateful

Thanks

Comment: Please edit your question and include the code that you have tried with or a minimal reproducible example, then we can help you troubleshoot any issues you might have with that.

Comment: Yes, use a DB (`sqlite` could be enough for your use case). You need to learn a bit of `SQL` in order to insert the data and query it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As an alternative to creating a database using SQL to query the data, you could also store the data in a pandas DataFrame (and locally in a .csv or .xlsx file).

The feasability depends on how many energy entries you have in each file, but pandas is capable of processing millions of rows very quickly.

Your dataframe could have two columns, with the first column storing the filenames and the second column storing the energy values:

| Filename | Energy values |
| --- | --- |
| filename1 | 6.36271 |
| filename1 | 5.37679 |
| filename1 | 165.742 |
| filename1 | 6.53952 |
| filename2 | 7.3 |
| filename2 | 6.36271 |

And then you can iterate through your list of energy entries and for each entry, filter the DataFrame to only show the rows in which this entry was found.

For example the search for `6.36271` would then return this DataFrame:

| Filename | Energy values |
| --- | --- |
| filename1 | 6.36271 |
| filename2 | 6.36271 |

And then you have all the files containing the energy value in the Filename column.

If you post a minimal working example of your code, I could update the answer with a possible implementation.

Comment: This seems easily feasible for me since I have some experience with pandas, I will give it a try and let you know asap. My code contains some sensitive information, so it will need some heavy edit to be shared... If nothing else works I will edit it and post it